# How to set the base tag href attribute in Sapper?

Tags: svelte, sapper

How can I modify the value of the `<base>` href attribute in Sapper ?

As per the [documentation](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#sapper_export), I tried `sapper export --basepath foldername` which (correctly) creates a `foldername` folder in `__sapper__/export`  but does not update the base tag href value with the expected "/foldername" value in the created index.html file. The output stays `<base href="/" />`

My goal is to deploy my SPA on a GitHub Pages subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I just found is to edit `/src/server.js` and use the first argument:

```js
    .use(
        'foldername',  // <-- here
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
```